# Get the difference in hours with an sql

Tags: php, sql

I have a question regarding an sql. I have the table

```
date                        id             
2015-03-17 00:06:12         143
2015-03-17 02:06:12         143
2015-03-17 09:06:12         143
2015-03-17 10:10:10         200
```

For each id I want to get with sql the difference in hours (last date - first date). For example : user with id = 143 I need to get : 9 hours the difference. For user 200 no difference because it have only one date. I have no idea how to do that. Can you help me please ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server`?  They are not the same thing.

Comment: There is no SQL92 db date compare standard as such - every vendor provides their own functions.

Comment: For user 143 isn't it 9 hours?

Comment: Yes, it's 9, sorry...I will modify

Comment: And what database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

mysql:

```
select A1.id, 
       datefiff(A1.xDate,A1.nDate)*24 + timediff(A1.xDate,A1.nDate) as HourDiff
from
(
select id, max(Date) as xDate, min(Date) as nDate
from myTable
group by id
) A1
```

SQL server:

```
with A1 as
(
    select id, max(Date) as xDate, min(Date) as nDate
    from myTable
    group by id
)

select id, datediff(HH, xDate, nDate) as HourDiff
from A1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in sql server:

```
    declare @table table ([date] datetime,id int)
    insert into @table values ( '2015-03-17 00:06:12', 143),
    ('2015-03-17 02:06:12', 143),
    ('2015-03-17 09:06:12', 143),
    ('2015-03-17 10:10:10', 200)

        select  max(Date) as maxDate, min(Date) as minDate, id into #temp
        from @table
        group by id


    select id, Cast((maxDate - minDate) as Float) * 24.0 as [difference]
    from #temp
   --OR
   --select id, DATEDIFF(second, minDate, maxDate) / 3600.0 as [difference]
   --from #temp

    drop table #temp
```